# why can't maven find a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

If I enter

```
mvn validate
```

It says all is well.

If I enter

```
mvn compile
```

It says it can't find a dependency.  If I navigate to the location in the local repository, both the jar and pom files are there.

Here is the actual error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.25:assemble (default) on project VCWH_Core_QueryService: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.25:assemble failed: Plugin org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.25 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.40.215] failed: Connection timed out
```

Also, if I click on link https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 it successfully shows me the online repository (although it goes to repo1, not repo) and I am able to navigate to org.codehaus.enunciate.maven-enunciate-plugin.1.25 and I can see that both the jar and pom file is there as well.  Same for https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a local firewall that's blocking outgoing connections from Java?

Comment: Connection timed out: do you use proxy with your browser ? then did you set proxy in maven settings?

Comment: Firefox connection settings does show "use system proxy settings" but where are those?  Anyway, if it already exists in the local repository, why should it even be looking to download it?  It tries even if I comment out the repository tag in the pom.xml.

Comment: I found out how to force maven to use only the local repo, use a -o, like this: "mvn compile -o"  but it's still giving the same error even though the dependency exists in the local repo.